# Vulkan parameters labeled/marked as "externally synchronized"

Tags: synchronization, thread-safety, vulkan

According to **Vulkan Specification**:

> "Any command parameters that are not **labeled** as externally
> synchronized..."

and also from **Vulkan Programming Guide**:

> In order to concretely define the threading requirements of various
> Vulkan commands, each parameter that must be protected from concurrent
> access by the host is **marked** as externally synchronized.

I've been going through Vulkan SDK headers, but found no such thing as any kind of informative annotation or DEFs to hint about "externally synchronized" characteristics of a Vulkan function and their parameters.

How am I supposed to know which objects passed to Vulkan functions as parameters need to be externally synchronized across threads?

In other words, where do these **LABELS/MARKS** live?

Comment: They're specified in the spec. The information block is labeled as `Host Synchronization`. [The information chapter also includes a list of common externally synchronized parameters.](https://registry.khronos.org/vulkan/specs/1.3-khr-extensions/html/chap3.html#fundamentals-threadingbehavior)

Comment: You can search the specification for the text "externally synchronized". The specification is not trying to trick you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've been going through Vulkan SDK headers

Header files are not the Vulkan specification. The Vulkan specification is talking about how **it** documents the behavior and requirements of these functions. That information is not in header files; it's in specification of what those functions do.

> How am I supposed to know which objects passed to Vulkan functions as parameters need to be externally synchronized across threads?

The same way you learn what those functions actually do: read the specification section on that function. You can even search for the words "externally synchronized" and find every parameter of any function so marked.